# Xcode 7.2.1 Beta Toolchain Prevents Sale on the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native, application-loader

I'm starting to test my React Native app in TestFlight on the App Store and I'm getting this INFO message when I use Application Loader to submit my Archive package to the App Store.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zad0dxt3akxb4cu/Screenshot%202016-03-11%2016.30.14.png?dl=0]

> INFO : "Beta Toolchain. This app has been built using beta toolchains. Apps built with beta toolchains are acceptable for TestFlight submission. Note that you will not be able to submit these builds for sale on the App Store."

So my questions are:

**1) What the heck is a Beta Toolchain?**

**2) How can I remove or replace these in order to submit it to the App Store?**

Here's my About screen from Xcode:

[image]

Xcode Location:

[image]

OS X About Screen:
[image]

Many Thanks!

Josh

Comment: You need to use the released version of Xcode from the Mac App Store. You cannot use a beta Xcode downloaded from the Apple developer site

Comment: @Paulw11 I thought I did install from the App Store. Not sure if you can tell, but I've added my Xcode About screen to the question. So, should I delete the Xcode I have in my Applications directory and then reinstall from the App Store?

Comment: If you have ever had a beta version installed it is possible that the beta command line tools are still in place. In Xcode go to "Xcode->Preferences->Locations" and check the command line tools version at the bottom of the dialog

Comment: Added Xcode location to the question....

Comment: Hmm. Not sure.  Are you using any pre-compiled libraries that may have been built with beta tools?  You could try re-installing Xcode.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll try re-installing and see how it goes. Hopefully no settings and stuff get wiped.

Comment: Make sure you're not running beta OS X

Comment: @sschale Damn, that could be it - see screenshot of OS X About screen in question.

Answer (score 0):

### OS X Beta

As @sschale mentioned in a comment, the culprit was my OS X El Capitan version.

You can see in my question that I was running the OS X beta of 10.11.4.

So, you can remove yourself from the OS X beta program quite easily by going to `System Preferences` > `App Store` > `Change`, as per: https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll

However, there is no easy way to reinstall a stable, public release of OS X without restoring from a backup:

[image]

Apple recommends that you just wait until the next public release if you can.

So, since they're on the sixth beta release of 10.11.4 I'm assuming they'll be releasing the public release soon so I can just wait, but certainly not good for people on a strict timeline.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Josh